# How To Write To The Windows 7 Registry HKLM

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, vbscript

I'm writing a vbscript that will write a registry value, to be precise the script should write the value of `DisableRemovableDriveScanning` value 0 to

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalwre\Scan\

but I soon realized that this doesn't work, because of user permissions.

I thought of saving the entries as a *.reg* and using the `runas` command to call the *.reg* file from a script as *SYSTEM*, but I don't know if it would work, and I haven't tried it out yet.

Would someone out there know of a way to write to `HKLM`?

**I'm using Windows 7 64 Bit**

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code, an Admin should be able to write there, not as system but as a local admin

Comment: Code is `wshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalwre\Scan\DisableRemovableDriveScanning", 0, "REG_DWORD"` and run in vbs as administrator

Comment: I would try your idea then update your question if you want people to help you.  **Your script file is exactly how I would do something like this.**

Comment: Thanks, I have tried everything that I could think of but it would not work, since the value is locked by the Microsoft Antimalware process (MSE) and this process cannot be disabled, so I'm stuck.